# How can I make jsonschema optional?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
  "required": ["firstName", "lastName", "age"]
}
```

*(edited after @gregdennis's answer)*

Given the above schema, a valid data would be

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21
}
```

But I want to make it "optional", as in I want to allow empty object

```
// should pass
{}
```

But not half schemas

```
// Shouldn't pass
{
    "firstName": "John"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is already optional, so the empty object should pass.  In order to make those properties required you need to put them in a `required` keyword.

```
"required": [ "first name", "last name", "age" ]
```

But just adding this keyword removes the ability to validate the empty object.

To fix that, wrap this in a `oneOf` asking with another schema that *only* accepts the empty object.

```json
{
  "oneOf": [
    { "const": {} },
    {
      // your schema from above along with required
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah I copy pasted that without looking too deeply into it actually, my original schema was being generated hence the overlook. This does help, though. Thanks!